# Change function component to class component syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a project in react and tried to change a functional component to class component in order to use `this.state` etc... However, I am receiving an error `Missing semicolon. (22.11)`.  How can I fix this in order to continue my project?
This is my code:

```
import React from 'react'

import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation'
import LogIn from './components/LogIn/LogIn'
import Converter from './components/Converter/Converter'

import './App.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
    }
  }
}

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Navigation />
        <LogIn />
        <Converter />
     </div>
   );
 }


export default App
```

Line 22.11 is the render word!

Comment: Hi, you need to move `}` from line 16 to line 29.

Answer (score 1):

```html
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {}
  }



  render () {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Navigation />
        <LogIn />
        <Converter />
     </div>
   );
 }
}


export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

There are certain errors in code [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-perlman-fvi5u?file=/src/App.js)

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
    }
  }
  // }               This is extra


  render () {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Navigation />
        <LogIn />
        <Converter />
     </div>
   );
 }
}                   // Add extra `}` to close class


export default App;
```